# Maven dependencies with versions [0.0.0,999.999.999)

Tags: maven

I have this situation where we have a couple of maven repositories. Some are frontend..ish (JSP, Spring Controllers etc.) meant to be deployed as `war` files and others are for the hibernate mappings etc. which are used as dependencies.

I noticed that in most of the `pom.xml` files for the frontend..ish applications the dependencies are listed as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myco.backend</groupId>
            <artifactId>db-objects</artifactId>
            <version>[0.0.0,999.999.999)</version>
        </dependency>
```

To me this looks like terrible practice because of reasons listed below. I know that maven's `LATEST` was deprecated, but I don't know whether this was because of it being bad practice to use it.

Some cons I can think of using this:

- Maven has to download all versions but only uses latest.
- Using latest version makes one uncertain as to what versions are being deployed.
- Perhaps multiple versions can be active at the same time?
- Could be using `SNAPSHOT` versions if we're not careful

So my question is this: is there any upside to specifying the version as `[0.0.0,999.999.999)`? Any critique of this or suggestions of how to do it better would be appreciated.

P.S. I know some of the stack sites are not for opinion questions and this may be off-topic. If this is the case, please direct me to the correct site.

Comment: you missed the worst down side. what if the library releases a v2 with breaking changes?

Comment: The only use I can think of is blue sky development. Where you aren't trying to fix a version your trying to prove an idea. But even then you probably want to lock a major version, and be free on the minor-patch etc...

Comment: Not snapshot versions.